# How can I repair my two sloping concrete slabs?

Tags: repair, slab

I have a home I'm working on that has been in the family for a while. I have  two slabs ,one where the original home was built and another where it was added on.

The two slabs run the entire length of the backside of the home and butt up against each other. The add on section is level up until about the last 10 feet where it slops down (facing back) The original slab also have issues but it more of a hill and valley affect on the same 10 ft or so.

At the highest and lowest I would say there is at least 2" rise from the valley but it is a gradual rise.

Any ideas on a fix for something this bad?

Answer (score 1):

If the slabs are stable and not moving (caused by poor compaction, sub surface drainage, or plate tectonics), commercial floor leveling (gypcrete is the most flexible and most economic in most areas) would quickly get you flat.

Some considerations will be:

1. Door clearances
2. Need to extend floor drains upwards
3. Stair rises affected
4. Need to clear out everything